# How to read many sound files in Matlab with a for loop?

Tags: matlab, audio

I want to read many wave files (.wav) one after another. I tried this code but matlab produces error message

```
can not open file
```

if n = number of wavefiles

```
for i=1:n 
[x,fs]=wavread('e:\database\i') ;
y(i,:)=x;
end
```

matlab consider it as filename not as variable, how can I write i as variable?

thanks

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING?

Comment: What is the `n:soundfiles` for?

Comment: `'e:\database\i'` is not a file, what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
A = {'filel.wav','file2.wav','file3.wav'};
for i=1:3
    [y, Fs] = wavread(A{i});
end
```

You can check other examples [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html).

Comment: you need to change the filenames with your own. There shouldn't be other problem.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works properly:)

```
A = {'file1.wav','file2.wav'};
for i=1:2
[y{i}, Fs{i}] = wavread(A{i});
end
```